# Disable lint rule in css

Tags: angular, lint, tslint

I want to disable a lint rule "unused styles" for a CSS file the flag
/* tslint:disable-next-line*/
is working in ts extensions but not working for css

**.css**

```
    /* tslint:disable-next-line*/
input:focus , input:valid       {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#606060;
}
```

still showing me lint error when I run **ng lint** command

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are using `stlyelint`:

```
/* stylelint-disable */
input:focus , input:valid       {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#606060;
}
/* stylelint-enable */
```

Comment: you can use:   /* stylelint-disable-next-line declaration-no-important */
  for a next line as requested in the question

```#id {
  /* stylelint-disable-next-line declaration-no-important */
  color: pink !important;
}```

as in the answer here: https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/714#issuecomment-244912552